# RenderBatch for game engine

Tags: c++, opengl

Recently, I implemented an `RenderBatch` class, which renders any objects, using a specific shader (with its configuration). I'd like to improve on the way my render process works.

**RenderBatch.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include "alpha/Shader.h"
#include "alpha/RenderComponent.h"
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include "alpha/Mesh.h"
#include "alpha/Transform.h"
#include "alpha/Model.h"

class ShaderConfiguration
{
public:
    ShaderConfiguration();
    virtual ~ShaderConfiguration();
    virtual void Update(Shader& shader);
    void SetProjectionView(const glm::mat4& projectionView){
        m_projectionView = projectionView;
    }
    glm::mat4 GetProjectionView() const{
        return m_projectionView;
    }
    void SetTransform(const Transform& transform){
            m_transform = transform;
    }
    Transform GetTransform(){
        return m_transform;
    }
protected:
    glm::mat4 m_projectionView;
    Transform m_transform;
};
typedef ShaderConfiguration DefaultShaderConfiguration;

///Render Batch is really low lovel... It is only advised to use it
///in case you want to experiment with GLSL shaders : for more basic uses,
///ModelBatch is actually integrated in the GameObject system...
class RenderBatch : RenderComponent
{
public:
    RenderBatch(){
        m_shader.loadFromFile(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "res/basicShader.glslv");
        m_shader.loadFromFile(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "res/basicShader.glslf");
        m_shader.CreateAndLink();
    }
    RenderBatch(Shader shader)
        : m_shader(shader){}
    virtual ~RenderBatch(){}
    void SetShader(Shader shader){this->m_shader = shader;}
    Shader GetShader()const {return m_shader;}

    ///Genereal way of updating -----------------> using polymorphism
    void UpdateShaderConfiguration(ShaderConfiguration* config){
        m_shader.Bind();
            config->Update(m_shader);
        m_shader.UnBind();
    }
    ///Update for simple rendering --------------> ProjectionView + Transform ()
    ///Equivalent of :
    ///DefaultShaderConfiguration defaultShaderConfiguration
    ///UpdateShaderConfiguration(&defaultShaderConfiguration);
    void Update(glm::mat4 projectionView, Transform transform){
        m_shader.Bind();
            glUniformMatrix4fv(
                m_shader.GetUniformLocation("MVP"),
                1,
                GL_FALSE,
                glm::value_ptr(projectionView * transform.GetModelView())
                );
        m_shader.UnBind();
    }
    void Render(Mesh& mesh){
        m_shader.Bind();
            mesh.Draw();
        m_shader.UnBind();
    }
    glm::mat4 GetProjectionViewMatrix(){
        return m_projectionView;
    }
    void SetProjectionViewMatrix(glm::mat4 projectionView){
        this->m_projectionView = projectionView;
    }
protected:
    Shader m_shader;
    glm::mat4 m_projectionView;
};
```

**RenderBatch.cpp**

```
#include "alpha/RenderBatch.h"

ShaderConfiguration::ShaderConfiguration()
    : m_projectionView(glm::mat4(1))
{}
ShaderConfiguration::~ShaderConfiguration(){}

void DefaultShaderConfiguration::Update(Shader& shader){
    glUniformMatrix4fv(
    shader.GetUniformLocation("MVP"),
    1,
    GL_FALSE,
    glm::value_ptr(m_projectionView * m_transform.GetModelView())
    );
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
 ///example 1 ---->using defaults
 RenderBatch batch = RenderBatch();
 Mesh mesh("res/Test.obj");     
 Camera camera;     

 while(isRunning)
 {
     /*Update */
     batch.Update(camera.Combined(), transform)         
     /*some more update code...*/

     /*Render*/
     batch.Render(mesh);
 }

 ///example 2 ---->using custom configuration
 RenderBatch batch = RenderBatch();
 Mesh mesh("res/Test.obj");     
 Camera camera;     
 ShaderConfiguration config;     

 while(isRunning)
 {
     config.SetProjectionView(camera.combined());
     config.SetTransform(transform)
     /*Update */
     batch.Update(config);         
     /*some more update code...*/

     /*Render*/
     batch.Render(mesh);
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bit of misnomer with `RenderBatch`. The term "batch rendering" is normally associated with grouping several geometries that share the same rendering attributes (textures/materials/etc) to render then together and avoid expensive state changes. Your class is just a wrapper around a `Shader`, so I don't see much reason for its existence, when all that could be part of `Shader` instead.

There is also an excessive amount of shader binding/unbinding going on inside `RenderBatch`. You definitely don't want to do that, changing shader programs is a [very expensive operation](http://www.ozone3d.net/public/jegx/201401/opengl_state_changes_stats.jpg).

That's one of the pitfalls of attempting to integrate OpenGL with OOP. The library was just not made to be used like that; it relies heavily on global state. This will change in the future with the new "bindless" OpenGL, but that's for version 4.5 and above.

Another potential issue that I see here is that `RenderBatch` is taking its `Shader` parameter by value, thus making a copy of it. How are you dealing with the internal GL shader program handle in this case? Even though you can copy the integer handle given to you by OpenGL, you can't copy the underlaying shader object itself. So I'm wondering if you are not winding up with duplicate shader handles through your program that will get deleted multiple times by calls to `glDeleteProgram` or even leak. Yet another problem of mixing a very C-ish API with C++. You have to be extra careful to avoid these sorts of mistakes. Be very aware that you are mixing two distinct programming languages in the same project.

Comment: Thansk :) The only question would  on integrating shaders without having the user writing any g glsl code, or caring about updating shader uniforms ...

Comment: @MattMatt, well you could hide the shaders under a layer similar to the old fixed function pipeline (look at code samples from GL 1.x). That might make the code simpler for users with little experience on graphics, but it would certainly limit more advanced users that do want to write custom shaders.

Comment: Oh, you mean like gl.begin() gl.end() ? how ? an example : )?

Comment: @MattMatt something like that yes, you can emulate things like `glTranslate` and such, if you think the target audience of your code would benefit from that. More advanced users will prefer having explicitly control over things like shader/texture bindings and updates though.

Comment: Ok, so the user could attach a shader to glbegin() and draw different meshes with it ! But what about things like the transform matrix ?

Comment: @MattMatt, simplest possible solution would be having it at some global point of access, like a `Renderer` class. But like I said, are you sure doing this is worth it? A better approach would be to just let the user handle shaders as he sees fit, IMO. Don't try to hide things that are common ground on modern graphics programming.

Comment: Thank you : ) I think I'm going follow your advice, and just leave everything as it is; but wouldn't there be a way to take of the burden from the user to update uniforms : that's a question that has been bugging me of for a while...

Comment: @MattMatt, graphics libraries are usually built of several layers. The layer dealing with shaders is fairly low-level. That layer has to send data to the GPU somehow, today this is done with shader uniforms. A higher level layer would comprise of a *material* system. The material then feeds its shaders with rendering parameters, so that the shader can pass them on to the GPU. But otherwise, it's no burden the update a few shader parameters. that's just how things work, only it is not very OOPy.

Comment: ah... ok. But what is a Material ? What parameters does it have ?

Comment: There isn't a single agreement on the term, but normally it is "the set of parameters defining how to shade a surface". Add to that textures, lighting parameters, shaders, among other things. I see that you are dealing with OBJ models, so you can think of the MTL file that comes with it as a material.

Comment: Then everything falls into place :) I was searching for a way to pass lighting properties to glsl : I can wrap them in a material class, and pass to the shader ! What about light ? Can I pass them like that too ?

Comment: @MattMatt, not sure exactly what you mean by light, but you would normally have a class for that too... But let's avoid extending this comment section too much. Consider asking an actual question at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ or StackOverflow if you have something more specific to ask.

Comment: And for the leak, I delete = and copy constructor  ---> changed it to a move constructor, so things get only deleted once !